# Linear model question regarding scale of variables

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation

I want to perform linear regression using the following command:

`lm(clinicVisits ~ clinicRank)` where `clinicVisits` is the number of visits to a clinic, and `clinicRank` is the rank of the clinic.

`clinicVisits` is an integer in the range of 1–200K, and clinicRank is a continuous variable and has a range of  1.0–150.0 where 1.0 is the best ranking.

I am trying to predict what an increase in rank will mean in terms of number of visits, as I believe there is a relationship between the two, so I am seeking this linear regression equation:

```
clinicVisits = y intercept + clinicRank*(b1)
```

I also assume that `b1` will be an increasingly negative number as the `clinicRank` gets smaller (i.e. closer to 1, the best rank).

Do I need to apply a scale to the variables since the `clinicRank` is relatively small compared to visits, or a log to the `clinicVisits` since it has a relative large range?

Comment: Hi gung: this is my first time posting so I see the editing changes you made and I will conform to them in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Since your dependent variable is count data, you should have a look at Poisson regression, i.e., [generalized linear models](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/glm.html). However, I'm not sure why you expect a linear relationship between your two variables. Maybe you could provide at least a plot of your data?